# What is simplest way to expand/collapse rows on HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the simplest possible way to have some rows on an HTML page that expand (and collapse) on being clicked?

Background:
I am using a bespoke CMS into which I can paste HTML and can also edit the CSS. However I am unable to add in special libraries.

The problem I have is that when I click on to expand, the browser goes to the top of the screen rather than staying in position.

My code looks roughly like this:

```
  <body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function toggleView(id, link) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if (e.style.display == '') {
      e.style.display = 'none';
      link.innerHTML = '(+)';
    } else {
      e.style.display = '';
      link.innerHTML = '(-)';
    }
  }

  </script>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  This is my headline <a href="#" onclick="toggleView('content', this)">(+)</a>

  <div id="content" style="display:none">
  This is my detailed content Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nunc fermentum.
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  &nbsp;

  </body>
```

Can this be done in pure CSS or is it better to use Javascript?

Sorry for newbie question, but I can't find the answer elsewhere.

J

Comment: Remove the `href="#"`. This is causing the browser to jump to that anchor point, which is the top of the page. Instead use `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: Brilliant! Easy when you know how  :)
Many thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using JQuery .

```
$("#content").slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code you could use:

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

instead of:

`href="#"`

But here's is a simpler example for you!

```
<div class="example2">
    <p>Text Here.</p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.example2').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-example2" class="button">Open/Close</a>');
    $('a#toggle-example2').click(function() {
        $('.example2').slideToggle(1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

JSFiddle:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/pe5VN/2/)